# Remove this [upgrade]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/upgrade) has over 1500 Questions, but only 6 Followers; looks like people don't exactly find useful. It's about all manner of upgrade issues. Does it deserve to stick around?

Comment: Few followers doesn't necessarily mean it's not useful.

Comment: @SamuelLiew but people [not answering those questions](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/upgrade/topusers) supports it

Comment: @SamuelLiew: There's no unambiguous meaning to "upgrade". It can refer to an extremely wide range of activities and subjects, not all of which are even in scope for SO.

Comment: @duskwuff I agree that "upgrade" by itself is quite ambiguous but when used in context with other tags, that defines the context.

If you look at the questions, many of them do have tags that specify what sort of upgrade they are referring to. If we remove the "upgrade" tag then it'll probably need to be replaced with many tags, one for each thing people are trying to upgrade eg. "mysql-upgrade", "windows-upgrade", etc. since these are the very sorts of problems that people often encounter and need to ask on here.

Comment: @reagleton tags like [tag:mysql-upgrade] sounds more useful than a [tag:mysql][tag:upgrade] combo. At least one can follow such a tag if she was interested in MySQL upgrades, and not MySQL in general. A good guideline: a tag should be useful on its own.